# Add Google Custom Search Engine to omnibox

Tags: google-search, omnibox

I've created my Google Custom Search Engine here https://www.google.com/cse

When I add it to omnibox with rightclick and try to use it I receive:
[image]

It's not unexpectable because search url in that case is:

https://www.google.com/cse/publicurl?search=%s&bgresponse=

while my public url looks like that: 

https://www.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=239428934982349832894:slkdfj9024

So, how can I add Google Custom Search to omnibox or is such possibility totally blocked by Google intentionally?

Comment: You see the `%S` in original search string? That gets replaced with whatever it is you search for when you type it in the omnibox and hit enter. You need to do a regular search using your CSE and figure out where in the search URL, the search string appears, replace it with `%S` and use that URL as the search URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` in the search URL is a placeholder for your search keywords.

When you search for something using the omnibox (say, "apples") the `%s` is replaced with your search keywords.
For example:

```
http://google.com/search?q=%s

would be

http://google.com/search?q=apples
```

So your CSE search URL would probably have to look like this:

```
https://www.google.com/cse?cx=239428934982349832894:slkdfj9024&q=%s
```